# SQL to grab all customers even if they don't have an order

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is a SQL statement that grabs orders for customers. I would like to modify it, so that it will include customers that don't have an order, however I am unsure as to the best way to do this:

```
SELECT 
    CT.ACCOUNTNUM,CT.STOREGROUPID,CT.STOREID, ST.STORENAME,
    CT.CITY,PT.ORIGSALESID,PT.DELIVERYDATE,PT.ITEMID,IT.BRANDID,
    IT.SIZEID,IT.SPECIALTYTYPEID,SUM(PT.QTY) AS Qty,
    dbo.ConvertUnitQty(PT.itemid,PT.salesunit,'DZ',PT.dataareaid,sum(pt.qty)) as  ConsumeQtyDz
FROM
    CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS PT 
    JOIN SALESTABLE ST ON ST.SALESID = PT.ORIGSALESID 
 AND ST.DATAAREAID = PT.DATAAREAID
    JOIN CUSTTABLE CT ON ST.CUSTACCOUNT = CT.ACCOUNTNUM 
 AND ST.DATAAREAID = CT.DATAAREAID
    JOIN INVENTTABLE IT ON IT.ITEMID = PT.ITEMID 
 AND IT.DATAAREAID = PT.DATAAREAID
WHERE
    (ST.DATAAREAID = @COMPANY) AND
    (PT.DELIVERYDATE BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE) AND
    IT.BRANDID IN (@BRANDID) AND
    IT.SIZEID IN (@SIZEID) AND
    IT.SPECIALTYTYPEID = (@SPECIALTYTYPE) AND
    CT.ASISTOREGROUPID IN (@STOREGROUPID)
GROUP BY
    CT.ACCOUNTNUM,CT.STOREGROUPID,CT.STOREID,ST.STORENAME,
    CT.CITY,PT.ORIGSALESID,PT.DELIVERYDATE,PT.ITEMID,IT.BRANDID,
    IT.SIZEID,IT.SPECIALTYTYPEID,PT.SALESUNIT,PT.DATAAREAID
```

Comment: Did somebody simply piled all the projected fields into the GROUP BY clause until the query seemed to pass? That query is horrible.

Answer (score 1):

May be like this

```
SELECT
    CT.ACCOUNTNUM, CT.STOREGROUPID, CT.STOREID, ST.STORENAME, CT.CITY, PT.ORIGSALESID, PT.DELIVERYDATE, PT.ITEMID, IT.BRANDID, IT.SIZEID, IT.SPECIALTYTYPEID, SUM(PT.QTY) AS Qty, dbo.ConvertUnitQty(PT.itemid,PT.salesunit,'DZ',PT.dataareaid,sum(pt.qty))as ConsumeQtyDz
FROM
    CUSTPACKINGSLIPTRANS PT
LEFT JOIN
    SALESTABLE ST ON ST.SALESID = PT.ORIGSALESID AND ST.DATAAREAID = PT.DATAAREAID
LEFT JOIN
    CUSTTABLE CT ON ST.CUSTACCOUNT = CT.ACCOUNTNUM AND ST.DATAAREAID = CT.DATAAREAID
LEFT JOIN
    INVENTTABLE IT ON IT.ITEMID = PT.ITEMID AND IT.DATAAREAID = PT.DATAAREAID
WHERE
    (ST.DATAAREAID = @COMPANY OR ST.DATAAREAID = IS NULL)
    AND (PT.DELIVERYDATE BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE)
    AND (IT.BRANDID IN (@BRANDID) OR IT.BRANDID IS NULL)
    AND (IT.SIZEID IN (@SIZEID) OR IT.SIZEID IS NULL)
    AND (IT.SPECIALTYTYPEID = (@SPECIALTYTYPE) OR IT.SPECIALTYTYPEID IS NULL)
    AND (CT.ASISTOREGROUPID IN (@STOREGROUPID) OR CT.ASISTOREGROUPID IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    CT.ACCOUNTNUM, CT.STOREGROUPID, CT.STOREID, ST.STORENAME, CT.CITY, PT.ORIGSALESID, PT.DELIVERYDATE, PT.ITEMID, IT.BRANDID, IT.SIZEID, IT.SPECIALTYTYPEID, PT.SALESUNIT, PT.DATAAREAID
```

Comment: +1 - Left joins are certainly what you want if you don't desire the 'can omit some of your records' part of inner joins (and just 'join' is implicitly an inner join).

Comment: The WHERE clause will filter out the outer joined records because of NULL values. Besides, this naive addition of LEFT to every join by no means would result in adding every customer, including those with no orders.

Comment: @Remus Rusanu, without the complete schema it is quite difficult to understand what the OP wanted but I tried to give an approach that would certainly require tweaks. Also, the where clause is updated to include the NULLs caused by LEFT OUTER JOIN. Obviously this would cause dups but again, don't have complete picture to eliminate those dups.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something, but...

```
SELECT * FROM [customerTable]
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum SQL to show every thing about every customer is:

```
select * from custtable;
```